# Template method pattern issue

Tags: java, design-patterns

if I have an abstract `Parent` class which has a `templateMethod` and a concrete `Child` class :

```
abstract class Parent
{
    final void templateMethod()
    {
        foo();
    }

    abstract void foo();
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    @Override
    void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

what should i do if i only want the user to know that `templateMethod` and do not want to expose `foo` method to class `Child`'s user while let the Child class define the implementation of `foo` method ?
Or, is template method not suitable in this case? Then, is there any other strategies i can use?

Comment: Make the templateMethod() public, but the foo() method protected. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by JB Nizet in the comment, you could do:

```
abstract class Parent {
    final void templateMethod() {
        foo();
    }

    abstract protected void foo();
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Since `Parent.foo()` is `protected`, only subclasses of `Parent` can call the method.

You might also find this question helpful: [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)